# Non editable field elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, updates

Is it possible to make an elastic search field non editable? in a way that the field value can not be updated after indexing the document?

Comment: could you explain the use case? there is a case where you set the index read-only to a particular user group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Field-level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/6.2/field-and-document-access-control.html) - you need X-Pack Security and you need to define the right permissions - or set the entire index as read-only as it was already mentioned.